# Train Database Project

Tags: sql, database, oracle

[image: simplified train database]

I am making a project of a train/railway system.

My problem is I don't know how to relate the route of a given train so that the user of the database knows if he/she wants to go from A to B ,what are the stations between A and B.

Please give me suggestions or any kind of tips as this is the first project I am working on!

Comment: Nothing in your database explicitly describes which stations have connections to which other stations.  Without that, how do you expect to know which stations are between A and B?  Even with that, you could find the trip with he fewest stops, but that doesn't mean there are actually any trains that go that route *(maybe you have to change half way, or go some indirect route with more stops)*.  You appear to need an extra table with the itinerary/timetable of each train...

Comment: "The requirements are: minimum 10 tables." Sounds like a homework or job interview question.. Besides it's hard to suggest a table structure/changes/suggestions  without project information or used data what need to be stored/queried

Comment: Minimum 10 tables? There's only 9 in that image. Did you forget to include the RegularSchedule table?  Btw, what have you tried?  Or are you just looking for a free coding service?

Comment: @LukStorms yes i tried adding a schedule table , but then I changed my mind, because I thought it was too similar to the announcements table and was containing the same informations, and I originally visualised it some other way.
y

Comment: You need to get an understanding of what kind of data those tables contain.   I'm assuming that the Announcement is used for delays/rerouting etc. So it wouldn't contain the complete schedules.  But to be honest, this might be a question that's probably too complicated & timeconsuming for someone to spend their free time on.

Comment: Yes, Announcement is used for an actual live version of  the schedule..well part of it at least..